# cypress code coverage for ionic application

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, cypress, code-coverage

We followed code coverage for cypress typescript in ionic application.

folder structures `/cypress/e2e/home.cy.ts,`

cypress/plugins/index.ts

```
 module.exports = (on, config) => {
      require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config);
      require('cypress-terminal-report/src/installLogsPrinter')(on);
    
    
      return config;
    };
```

cypress/support/e2e.ts

```
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support';
```

cypress.config

```
setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return require('./cypress/plugins/index.ts')(on, config);
    },
```

am getting below result [image]

all % showing Zero .Could you please guide us how to show % ,Lets us know what we did wrong